# Getting the size of an image inputstream

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream, bitmapfactory

I need to get the height and width of the image found in the inputstream. Here is what I did:

```
private Boolean testSize(InputStream inputStream){
        BitmapFactory.Options Bitmp_Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmp_Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(getResources(), new TypedValue(), inputStream, new Rect(), Bitmp_Options);
        int currentImageHeight = Bitmp_Options.outHeight;
        int currentImageWidth = Bitmp_Options.outWidth;
        Bitmp_Options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    if(currentImageHeight < 200 || currentImageWidth < 200){
        Object obj = map.remove(pageCounter);
        Log.i("Page recycled", obj.toString());
        return true;
    }
    return false;}
```

Skipping to the problem at point:

It change BitmapFactory.Options even if I forced it to be false after calculation on my second method below.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(InputStream InpStream){
    Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InpStream);//Null.
    return originalBitmap;
}
```

Now to my question is there another way of getting the size and width of an image from an inputstream? I really need help on this any help is greatly appreciated.

```
                ZipInputStream zip = null;
                zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(getFileLocation()));
                for(ZipEntry zip_e = zip.getNextEntry(); zip_e != null ; zip_e = zip.getNextEntry()){
                    if(zip_e.isDirectory()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String file_zip = zip_e.getName();
                    String comparison = map.get(pageCounter).getHref();
                    if(file_zip.endsWith(comparison)){
                        SpannableString Spanable_String = new SpannableString("abc");
                        if(testSize(zip)){
                            map.remove(pageCounter);
                            return false;
                        }
                        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(zip);
                        if(bitmap == null){
                            map.remove(pageCounter);
                            return false;
                        }
                        image_page.put(zip_e.getName(), zip);
                        Drawable drawable_image = new FastBitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                        drawable_image.setBounds(0,0,drawable_image.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable_image.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable_image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                        Spanable_String.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        tv.setText(Spanable_String);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the setting Bitmp_Options.inJustDecodeBounds to true is being persisted for subsequent calls to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`?

Comment: Yes, I am saying it's true. For some reason without testSize method it will work properly same inputstream and same source. I find it a very strange behaviour that I had to report it as a bug.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that would certainly not be the expected behavior. I'm not sure that there is another (good) way to get the image size from an input stream.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls these functions?

Comment: I will do it but for confidential reason for my company I can't reveal most of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main problem is not with the `BitmapFactory.Options`, but with the `InputStream`. The stream is sequential, therefore when you read the stream to decode the image for size only, the pointer in the stream is moving.  Next, when you're calling `decode` again to actually decode the bitmap, the stream pointer is no longer at the beginning of the bitmap, and you get `null` because the partial stream cannot be decode.

You would need to reset the stream.  Depending on what that stream is, you might be able to use `.mark` and `.reset` on it.  Essentially, you'd do something like this:

```
private Boolean testSize(InputStream inputStream) {
    BitmapFactory.Options Bitmp_Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmp_Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    inputStream.mark(inputSteram.available());

    BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(getResources(), new TypedValue(), inputStream, new Rect(), Bitmp_Options);

    inputSteram.reset();

    int currentImageHeight = Bitmp_Options.outHeight;
    int currentImageWidth = Bitmp_Options.outWidth;
    Bitmp_Options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    if(currentImageHeight < 200 || currentImageWidth < 200){
        Object obj = map.remove(pageCounter);
        Log.i("Page recycled", obj.toString());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can check whether your `InputStream` supports this or not by calling `markSupported` on it.  If that returns `true` then you can use the above technique.  If it returns `false`, then the above method will not work and you will actually need to close and reopen the stream again before decoding the full bitmap.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me many hours of trying to figure this out. Thank you again for telling me it is sequential.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you were calling this on the same instance of an inputstream. That makes sense.

Comment: nice answer! unfortunatly markSupported is set to false in my case :(

Comment: @zhar Such InputStreams (that do not support mark/reset) can be simply wrapped into BufferedInputStream.